# Combine: Init mutating 'self' parameter

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm messing around with Combine code and Swift UI and came across this problem. Effectively I want to pass a `Publisher` into a `View` and have that `View` update every time the publisher publishes an update.

Here's a sample playground that will not compile. Instead it puts up an error - *`Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter`* on the `.sink(...` line.

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {

    let cancellable: AnyCancellable
    @State var current: Int = 0

    init<P>(publisher: P) where P: Publisher, P.Output == Int, P.Failure == Never {
        cancellable = publisher.sink { value in
            self.current = value
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(current)")
    }
}

let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
let x = MyView(publisher: subject)
subject.send(5)
```

Currently I've changed the code to use an `ObservableObject` view model with the value inside it and telling that object to send an update. But I'm interested how others have gotten around this problem as I'd like a none view model option too.

What have you guys done?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `onReceive` to subscribe to Combine `Publisher`s in SwiftUI `View`s. That way the SwiftUI runtime will manage the subscription for you, even while your view may be recreated many times.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State var current: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(current)")
            .onReceive(somePublisher) { self.current = $0 }
    }
}
```

However, using `ObservableObject`s directly is often a better idea, as they integrate directly into SwiftUI.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

class Model: ObservableObject {
    var current: Int = 0 {
        willSet {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(model.current)")
    }
}

let model = Model()
let myView = MyView().environmentObject(model)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: myView)

model.current = 5
```

Comment: You could use the `@Published` property wrapper in `Model`